# Parsting tree with getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file with order data. The JSON file is formatted like this:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {"name": "Peter", "email": "peter@aol.com"}

    {"name": "David", "email": "david@aol.com"}

    { "name": "George", "email": "george@aol.com"}
  ]
}
```

As you can see; all the data is part of a branch called `"orders"` and then each order is its own branch, but the branch doesn't have a name.

I am trying to generate a list of the `"name"`s in the dataset.

With a simplified dataset, I would do something like:

```
$(data).each(function(i, name){
    $('#namesText').append($("li")
        .append($("li").append(name.name))
  });
})
```

This however doesn't work as the data is not in the first level of the tree.

My question is, how do I go down levels when the levels don't have a name?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `$(data.orders)`? I'm confused on what you mean by "then each order has its own branch, but the branch doesn't have a name."

Comment: `$(data.orders).each(function(i, order)` is probably what you're after, i.e. iterating over the `orders` array.

Comment: @george If the orders were in named branches, the data would look like this:     "single-order": [
       {
    "name": "Peter",
    "email": "peter@aol.com",
       }
      ]... What I'm saying is that there's no key for each dataset

Comment: @Adam $.each is working with arrays, data.orders or data["orders"] - is an array, the $.each function gets an array of objects, no need for keys, you are iterating over array!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a DFS problem where each object has keys that can possibly be a primitive data type or another object. Since the `name` field could be at any level in this given constraint you need to solve for, I would say use DFS algo where it traverses each key in the object and if there is another object, look into that until you find a `name` field. Better solution is to redesign the data structure so that you are guaranteed to know which level and location the `name` field is at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the `name` property from the elements of the `orders` array you could use `Array.map`:

```
const names = myJson.orders.map(o => o.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
namesText.innerHTML= data.orders.map(p=>`<li>${escape(p.name)}</li>`).join``
```

```js
var data = {
  "orders": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "email": "peter@aol.com",
    },
    {
      "name": "David",
      "email": "david@aol.com",
    },
    {
      "name": "George",
      "email": "george@aol.com",
    }
  ]
}

namesText.innerHTML= data.orders.map(p=>`<li>${escape(p.name)}</li>`).join``
```

```html
<ul id="namesText"></ul>
```